# Password reset link triggering "Privacy Error" in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

The problem is: when a user clicks "Forgot my password" from the login page, an email is sent to them with a link to reset their password, but when they click the link in the email, they are prevented from visiting it by their browser. The browser gives a "Privacy Error".

For example, Chrome displays `Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information from [app_name].heroku.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

This is a **Rails 5** app, using the **Devise** gem for authentication, and deployed to **Heroku**. Using **SendGrid** for these transactional emails. In config/environments/production.rb, `config.force_ssl = true`

This does not come up on any other pages of the app.

What is causing this warning from the browsers, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does the reset password link in the email use `http` or `https` for the protocol?

Comment: The reset password link in the email uses `https`. It follows the format `https://xxxxxxx.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=[very-long-token]` which redirects to `https://[app-name].heroku.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[token]`

Comment: Sendgrid should redirect to `https://[app-name].herokuapp.com`

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks Tom. I had it incorrect in the default_url_options in production.rb, and have now fixed it to `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '[app-name].herokuapp.com' }`.   If you want to put this as the answer I will select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your mailer is configured to use `https` as the site url.  Update your `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://< your domain name>' }
end
```

You can add this to other environment files as you deem appropriate.

For Heroku, your host should be `https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com`